# Get cmdlet parameter info for 3rd party modules

Tags: powershell

Is there any way in PowerShell to determine the types of function for third party modules which:

a) you do not have the source code for

b) are written in C#

alternatively is there such a thing as a PowerShell super type I can use ?

Comment: `Get-Command CommandName -Syntax` should show you the expected parameter types

Comment: So that gets me the arguments for the function I'm interested in and their types, its specifically the return value type that I'm after, which this does not appear to give me.

Comment: If the return type is declared, you can discover it with `(Get-Command CommandName).OutputType`

Answer (score 0):

Since only `Cmdlets` are written in C#, `ps1, psm1` files define functions. You could try:

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet  | select ModuleName -Unique
```

That will return all modules containing cmdlets. But I think there is no way to filter out the 3rd party ones since there is no forced naming scheme.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @ChrisAdkin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.